# How to find the series expansion of this function at x=0?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

$$f(x)=\sqrt{\tan(x)}$$
I know puiseux series but I don't know how to find the series expansion of this function.

Comment: Given that it is undefined for negative values near $0,$ how are you going to get a series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\sqrt{\tan(x)/x}$ has a removable singularity at $0$, with Maclaurin series (according to Maple)

$$ \sqrt{\frac{\tan(x)}{x}} = 1+\frac{1}{6} x^{2}+\frac{19}{360} x^{4}+\frac{55}{3024} x^{6}+\frac{11813}{1814400} x^{8}+ \ldots $$

so the Puiseux series is

$$ \sqrt{\tan(x)} = x^{1/2}+\frac{1}{6} x^{5/2}+\frac{19}{360} x^{9/2}+\frac{55}{3024} x^{13/2}+\frac{11813}{1814400} x^{17/2}+ \ldots$$

I hope you're not looking for a closed form of the coefficients.